# Styles from Geomedia (mdb with style library) to be used in qgis?

Tags: qgis, style, geomedia

We are trying to move some projects from Geomedia Professional to QGIS. Since we have large style libraries (stored as mdb) we are looking for a way to convert the styles to a format that QGIS can read. There is no export functionality in geomedia. Export in Access from mdb to xml failed when importing in stylemanager in QGIS. Can anyone help?

(Windows 7; Geomedia Professional 13; QGIS 1.8.0)

Comment: can you post a sample of the XML that you exported?

Comment: The error message says "Incorrect root tag in style:dataroot; XML of StyleProperties Table can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5wn998p64a2cjox/1BW4AY11V4